# Inline CSS in React - how to style multiple li elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, inline

I am trying to do some inline CSS style in my React components. I am aware of pros/cons and all of the fancy libraries out there but I'm curious about this specific case.

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';

const Menu = () => (
    <ul style={styles}>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
    </ul>
)

const styles = {
    listStyle: 'none',
}

export default Menu;
```

I want to apply some style to "li" elements, but how to do so without writing style={styles} for every single "li" element? For example, display:inline for all "li" elements **purely in javascript**?

P.S.: I'm aware of articles and resources (I read a lot of them), please, don't include such sources as answer, because it's really not helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Comment: Temani Afif thanks, but I already read couple of articles and I didn't find the answer for my specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium)
    to achieve what you want. Radium provides a
    [`Style`](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/tree/master/docs/api#style-component)
    component.

> **Style Component**
>
> The  component renders an HTML  tag containing a set of CSS rules. Using it, you can define an optional scopeSelector
>       that all selectors in the resulting  element will include.
>
> Without the  component, it is prohibitively difficult to write a  element in React. To write a normal  element,
>       you need to write your CSS as a multiline string inside of the
>       element.  simplifies this process, and adds prefixing and the
>       ability to scope selectors.
>
> If you include a scopeSelector, you can include CSS rules that should apply to that selector as well as any nested selectors. For
>       example, the following

Example taken straight from the README.

```
<Style
  scopeSelector=".scoping-class"
  rules={{
     color: 'blue',
     span: {
       fontFamily: 'Lucida Console, Monaco, monospace'
     }
  }}
/>
```

So for your case, it would be,

```
const Menu = () => (
  <div>
    <Style
      scopeSelector="li"
      rules={{
         color: "yellow"
      }}
    />
      <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Another way is to use [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components)

```
const StyledLi = styled.li`
   color: red;
`;

const StyledMenu = () => (
  <ul>
    <StyledLi>1</StyledLi>
    <StyledLi>2</StyledLi>
    <StyledLi>3</StyledLi>
    <StyledLi>4</StyledLi>
  </ul>
);
```

You can see it live at: https://codesandbox.io/s/29j6131jp

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated my answer to include the another alternative. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
const Li = (props) => {
    const styles = {
        listStyle: 'none',
    }
    return <li style={styles}>{props.text}</li>
}

const Menu = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
        <Li text="A" />
        <Li text="B" />
        <Li text="C" />
        <Li text="D" />
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is also another alternative to Hardik Modha answer. Thank you too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Define a css file where you will set a style for li, and include in the the .js file.

for example: in file.css:

```
li {
  font-size: 20
}
```

in file.js:

```
import './file.css'
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want to achieve this particular styling purely with javascript, if possible.

Comment: I answered your question which is: "I want to apply some style to "li" elements, but how to do so without writing style={styles} for every single "li" element?" :)

Comment: Ah.. so the rest of the question is just not important. Okay. I'll update my question with bold for other to understand it clearly.